# Shrink appcompat resources in Android

Tags: android, android-resources, shrink, shrinkresources

I would like to know how to remove appcompat resources.

To see my problem : In Android Studio, generate a new project with an empty Activity (backwards compatibility checked).
 Enable shrinkResources in release build type.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Generate signed APK, then go to Build => Analyze APK. See the 
[result of the analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xJZt.png)

It seems a lot of space is wasted by [unnecessary resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lns7e.png). How can I remove them ? I read the documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) and I already tried to create the file `res/raw/keep.xml` which contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:shrinkMode="strict" />
```

But it does nothing.

Comment: From the standpoint of the build tools, it is difficult to tell what parts of `appcompat-v7` are used and what parts are not.

Comment: Ok thanks CommonsWare. I will try to do it manually.